# Multiple Products, One Stock Quantity

Tags: stock

Good Afternoon,

I apologise if I ask or say anything seemingly ignorant or stupid however I am very new to Magento.

I work for a company that sells laptop LCD panels all over the world. We have been selling on websites such as Amazon and eBay for many years now and I've recently been tasked with setting the company up with our own online shop.

So far it all seems fairly self explanatory, and there's a wealth of knowledge available which is great. However...

We have thousands of eBay listings for one stock category on our database. Say one type of laptop LCD might fit 300 or different models of laptop, we would have an auction with each model in the title so that buyers can find the screen they need easily.

What I'm hoping to find out how we could possibly replicate this situation on Magento Community 2.3.1.

Ideally I'd like to be able to set up multiple products(?) that link to one category on our database, but with the added functionality that a purchase from any of these products reduces the stock level of the category as a whole.

Is there a way to do this with something like product options (1 product with a massive amount of options) or another way this can be done using an extension maybe?

Any information would be great as I would really like to get the stock management as accurate as possible.

Any pointers with this would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it this will work for 1000s of options but here is the dev docs for configurable products.

Magento 1:
https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable.html

Magento 2:
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html

Comment: Thank you for this information, unfortunately I think having this many configurations in a drop-down list would be incredibly impractical for the customers.

I was hoping there was either:
1. a way for product pages to all draw their quantity from the same location rather than all being individual. 

2. Alternately maybe there's a way to run some SQL that would update all other quantities for products of the same "type" when a sale is made?

I don't know where to start looking for the code that executes to reduce stock for a product after a sale, or if method 1 would be possible at all.

Comment: I think 1 would be the better option, but I'm not really sure how to implement that. I hope somebody else can give you a better answer sorry